# cpp - sqlite3 how to correctly bind `char` type and read it from the database

Tags: c++, sqlite

How to bind simple `char char_type;` and read it back from the sqlite3 database?

```
 char char_type;
 char_type = 'V';
 sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, char_type); // error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
```

/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:3430: error: too few arguments to function 'int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int, void (*)(void*))'

```
 // read it back?
 char_type = reinterpret_cast<char*> ( sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1) );
```

Comment: Well first is that `sqlite3_bind_text()` takes a *pointer*, so you can do `&char_type` for that. Also, why are you passing three arguments rather than 5?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, seems need to pass also `-1, , SQLITE_TRANSIENT`. And I will try `&char_type` as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a char type, only a string type. So you have to make it look like a string:

```
// bind
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, /* column */ 1, &char_type, 1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

// read
char_type = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)[0];
```

Alternatively, if you know all your data is always going to be one character, it's almost certainly more efficient to use an integer instead and simply cast it on the way in and out:

```
// bind
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, /* column */ 1, (int)char_type);

// read
char_type = (char)sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
```

Comment: thanks. (why `1, SQLITE_STATIC`, not `-1, , SQLITE_TRANSIENT` ?)

Comment: @abrahab: Because I made a mistake (see the edit) ;-) `1` indicates the length of the string -- if you pass a negative number it will try to find the null terminator, and you don't have one (because you don't actually have a string, just a `char`). `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` makes a copy of the string, which is correct in this case because the pointer to the variable on the stack might not live as long as the statement does.

Comment: Yes, it's always 1 character. How to cast it to the int correctly and read it again?

Comment: Actually, both a 7-bit integer and a one-character string [use one byte of storage](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format) in the database.

Comment: @CL.: I was referring more to the manipulation efficiency (it's generally faster to compare integers than strings, so faster sorting/indices/querying, and no allocation/deallocation ever has to be done when manipulating integers) than the space efficiency on disk. Also, I don't quite see where in that linked reference 1-byte strings use only one byte? Surely the length has to be stored somewhere too, unless there's a special serial type just for 1-byte strings, which I didn't see.

Comment: The string length is part of the type code, which exists anyway for every column.

Comment: @CL. Ah yes, I see now how it's done in the `sqlite3VdbeSerialType` and `sqlite3VdbeSerialTypeLen` functions (for some reason the docs just didn't click for me). You are of course correct. My bet is still on faster integer processing though.